# No request body in swagger-test

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, swagger

After a long search, I finally found [swagger-test](https://github.com/earldouglas/swagger-test) to be the best framework to test my REST services from a swagger spec. I followed the read me and the example in the Repo. This is my first `xamples` request/response pair.

```
"x-amples": [{
"description": "should save an object",
"request": {
    "params": {
        "app_id": "bengi",
        "table_name": "Student",
        "body": {
            "collectionName": "Student",
            "key": "mLiJB380x9893rjlaf0"
        }
    }
},
"response": {
    "status": 200,
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json"
    }
}}]
```

`app_id` and `table_name` are substituted very well in the `url`.

My problem is that the parameter `body` is never included in the http request. I know this because I have inspected the traffic from wireshark.
I am quite sure my specs are very okay because I have been running successful tests manually from Swagger-UI. Here is a screen shot of my console:
[image: when I run the tests]

Meaning my request is unauthorised due to missing `key` parameter which is in the request `body` above.

This is my js.js file called by `mocha`:

```
var swaggerTest = require('swagger-test');
var fs = require('fs');
var preq = require('preq');
var swaggerSpec;

var buffer  = fs.readFileSync('cb.json');
    swaggerSpec    = JSON.parse(buffer);
var xamples = swaggerTest.parse(swaggerSpec);


describe('specification-driven tests', function () {
  xamples.forEach(function (xample) {
    it(xample.description, function() {
        this.timeout(10000);
      return preq[xample.request.method](xample.request)
      .then(function (response) {
        assert.deepEqual(response, xample.response);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

What should I do to ensure that my request `body` is seen and used by `swagger-test`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several hours of crawling the web and getting no solution, I tried to go through the code and the modules used. This is what I found out that solved my problem:
My `x-amples` JSON is wrongly formatted, especially where I have placed my `body` element.

From my question

> `app_id` and `table_name` are substituted very well in the url.

Well that is because of this line:

```
 var xamples = swaggerTest.parse(swaggerSpec);
```

from the `test file`.

The main function of [swagger-test](https://github.com/earldouglas/swagger-test) Is to parse the Swagger specification file and extract all `x-ample` elements into an array as demonstrated by this line:

```
var xamples = swaggerTest.parse(swaggerSpec);
```

This means [swagger-test](https://github.com/earldouglas/swagger-test) does its work perfectly i.e:

1. Retrieve all `x-ample` extentions into an array.
2. Substitute the values in `params` element:

   ```
   "request": {
       "params": {
           "app_id": "bengi",
           "table_name": "Student",
           "body": {
               "collectionName": "Student",
               "key": "mLiJB380x9893rjlaf0"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   into the `url` template:

e>/data/{app_id}/{table_name}

3. Concatenate the `host`,`basePath` and `params` from the `swagger-spec` and `request` JSON to form a complete `uri`.

   All this is done in this code snippet which does the donkey work in

   ```
   function parseXample(spec, uri, method, xample) {
   var uriTemplate = template.parse(uri);
   var expandedUri = uriTemplate.expand(xample.request.params);
   xample.request.method = method;
   xample.request.uri = spec.host + spec.basePath + expandedUri;
   return {
       description: xample.description || method + ' ' + uri,
       request: xample.request,
       response: xample.response
   };
   ```

   }

From my question:

> My problem is that the parameter body is never included in the http request

The trick was in the [preq](https://www.npmjs.com/package/preq) module source code in the `getOptions([url],[o],[method])` method.

```
    if (o.body && o.body instanceof Object) {
        if (o.headers && /^application\/json/.test(o.headers['content-     type'])) {
            o.body = JSON.stringify(o.body);
        } else if (o.method === 'post') {
            o.form = o.body;
            o.body = undefined;
        }
    }
```

Argument `o` is `options` that is the `xample.request` object passed to preq from my test code:
    return preqxample.request.method
So it becomes clear that `xample.request.body` was in existent in my request object since it is at `xample.request.params.body`  and consequently the condition `if (o.body && o.body instanceof Object)`  does not pass and hence the assignment `o.body=JSON.stringify(o.body)` did not happen.

The final `x-ample` extension should look like this:

```
"x-amples": [{
    "description": "should save an object",
    "request": {
        "method": "put",
        "uri": "/data/{app_id}/{table_name}",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": {
            "collectionName": "Student",
            "key": "xxxxxx"
        },
        "params": {
            "app_id": "xxxxxx",
            "table_name": "xxxxxx"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json"
        }
    }
}]
```

Apart from the location of the `body` element, you must include the `headers` element, else you get an error.